# scite python import doesn't work

Tags: python, scite

I'm working on a simple project in Python since few weeks, i'm using Python 2.7 with SciTE on Win7

But last week i'd had to make some updates on my computer, since the import doesn't work and all of them were working before. I can't run my file from SciTE and from cmd.exe, but when i'm double clicking on the file.py in the windows explorator it works fine.
It was boring to do that, but it was working.

My problem is, I want to use cx_Freeze, but I need to launch it from cmd.exe by typing

```
python setup.py build
```

and this is the error I get:

```
File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
   from cx_Freeze import setup, Executables
ImportError: No module named cx_Freeze
```

And this is the setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executables

if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"

setup( name = "Interface JB-PDS",
       version = "1.0",
       executables = [Executables("main.py", base=base)]
     )
```

cx_Freeze is correctly installed.

I don't think i'm doing something wrong, but it's possible. Some of you have encountered this problem or know how to solve this ?

Comment: If you can't run Python script from SciTE or command shell, while you can run the script by double click in Explorer, means that Python is not set in your %PATH%. Your latter problem however doesn't seem to have any relation with SciTE, but with module you have problem with or perhaps with your whole Python setup.

Comment: Python is set in %PATH%, i've forgot to specify it.